# How can I make an orthographical projection image from perspective projection image?

Tags: python, image, perspective, perspectivecamera, orthographic

I want to be able to feed my program an image (probably from a camera) and get an Orthographic view of that image. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66563639/how-can-i-compute-orthographical-projection-image-from-perspective-projection-im) post but haven't been able to do it.

I would like a tutorial in python or something along those lines. I also don't mind if I distort or lose data from the image.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.